# Golang for loop permutations

Tags: go, combinations, permutation

I've been puzzling myself for around 5 hours now. I'm extremely new to Golang (2 day)...

I'm looking for a for loop that will create all permutations of a given sized string, using specific characters. Not only that, but it needs to be split into specific chunk sizes.. I'll try and visually show you what I need..

```
chars          := "abcdefghij"
string_size    := 6
blocks         := 5
start_position := 2
```

So the possibilities of this example would be 10 to the power of 6... so 1,000,000..

What I need is for this e.g. 1,000,000 to be split into 5 blocks mentioned above, so 200,000 guesses per for loop.

So specifying start position would lets say do something like

```
sections_usable := len(chars) / blocks
// sections_usable == 5
// this would then cherry pick 5 sections 
sections := make([]rune, blocks)
base_count := 0
for i := 0; i < blocks * sections_usable; i = i + sections_usable  {  
     sections[base_count] = rune(r[i])
     base_count++
}
for i, xi := range x {

    if i == 0 {

        // This is where its selecting the starting character
        // From the sections 
        p[i] = sections[block_to_use]

    } else {
        p[i] = r[xi]
    }

}
```

Heres an example of what data I'd want returned
using

```
chars          := "abcdefghij"
string_size    := 6
blocks         := 5
start_position := 2
```

So start position 0 would be "a", 1 would be "c", 2 would be "e"

so using 0

aaaaaa

aaaaab

aaaaac

aaaaad

....

abbbbb

abbbbc

abbbbd

....

acdddd

acddde

acdddf

NOW USING start position 2

eaaaaa

eaaaab

eaaaac

...

And so on, but the permutations must stop before it starts the next block i.e

ejjjjj

Comment: Trying to break a password?... `len(chars) / blocks` is 2, not 5, based on the values you've provided.  And where do you get the variable `r` from?  Does your code even compile?  I suggest you cut back the gradient and start with something simpler.

Comment: This wasn't a full sample of the code, I was asking for alternatives...